# Why can't I create virtual directories any more?

Tags: iis-7

I was working with IIS 7.0 and the problem is that my virtual directories under default web site got deleted. Now I am not able to add any new virtual directories.

When right clicking on the default website I get the following error displayed:

> there was an error while performing this operation...the application '/' does not exist.

Can any one help me in getting back my virtual directories?

Answer (score 1):

That's the same question as here: [virtual directories in iis7.0 got deleted in windows 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/86252/virtual-directories-in-iis7-0-got-deleted-in-windows-2008/90640#90640)

It sounds like editing applicationHost.config should turn up the config issue that will need to be manually adjusted.