# virtual directories in iis7.0 got deleted in windows 2008

Tags: iis-7

After  installing iis6.0 metabase compatibility and iis6.0  console in the iis7.0 ,i am not able to create new virtual directory in Default website( which is marked with a small red mark).

when i  right click on" Default website",it generates following message box

"there was an error while performing this operation...the application '/' does not exist."

and i am working in the windows 2008 environment .can any one help me in getting back my old virtual directories in default website?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the config file has a bad entry.  If you click around your sites and vdirs in IIS Manager you will probably get an error there too when you click on the bad folder.  See if you can delete it and create it again.

If you can't, take a look at c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and look for the bad vdir and manually clean up the config.  Make sure to save a copy of the file before you start, or run appcmd add backup BeforeSabashTroubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, error on default web site.

I open "applicationHost.config" file and remark config for Default IIS site was missing undet Sites -> Default Web Site

I've add this and it works now

```
<application path="/">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
</application>
```